# Bind to Combobox in Datagrid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, binding, datagrid

I want to create a Datagrid, something look like this:
[DatagridDesign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ovx0.jpg)

To explain: I want to have a Datagrid with some comboboxes (Type, Quantity, Cell), which will have nothing selected but containing items. For simplicity let's say Header(Type: will have options of type1, type2, type3), (Quantity: 1, 2, 3), (Cell: cell1, cell2, cell3). I want the user to select from comboboxes, also when "adding row" will give another row containing items, and so on. In the end I want to save them to the Database.

As I am new to WPF and the concept of binding, I tried something like this:

My VB.Net code:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Class MainWindow
    Dim appRow As New ObservableCollection(Of Employee)

    Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    appRow.Add(New Employee With {.Cell = New ObservableCollection(Of String)({"cell1", "cell2", "cell3"}), .Type = New ObservableCollection(Of String)({"type1", "type2", "type3"})})
    appRow.Add(New Employee With {.Cell = New ObservableCollection(Of String)({"cell1", "cell2", "cell3"}), .Type = New ObservableCollection(Of String)({"type1", "type2", "type3"})})
    
    DataContext = appRow
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Employee
    Dim _Type As New ObservableCollection(Of String)
    Dim _Cell As New ObservableCollection(Of String)

    Public Property Type() As ObservableCollection(Of String)
        Get
            Return _Type
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of String))
            _Type = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Cell() As ObservableCollection(Of String)
        Get
            Return _Cell
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of String))
            _Cell = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And my Xaml Code:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Testing"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>
    <DataGrid Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Type}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Quantity" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Margin="2">
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="1" />
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="2" />
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="3" />
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Cell" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Cell}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
```

Now, this is working. But I want to set items in the class itself, so when it gets called it initializes with values. So I tried:

```
Class MainWindow

Sub New()
InitializeComponent()

DataContext = New Employee()
End Sub
```

End Class

```
Public Class Employee
    (Same as before...)
    Sub New()
        Cell = New ObservableCollection(Of String)({"cell1", "cell2", "cell3"})
        Type = New ObservableCollection(Of String)({"type1", "type2", "type3"})
    End Sub
End Class
```

And Xaml stays the same. The same way I bind normal comboboxes to my WPF and that is working. But with Datagrid, it's not. It's also showing no error and runs normally.

Does anyone have an idea what is I am doing wrong? Or how can I get the result that I am trying to get?
I really am stuck here for the last few days! I really appreciate your help and afford!

SideNote: Why Binding in Datagrid so complicated! Any idea where I can get a complete overview? For example (I am still confused why Datacontext, itemsource, ObservableCollection(why `list of list of string` doesn't work)). Any post or website with a clear concept? I went through a lot of examples and posts, but everybody is having a different approach than another and I am lost after sometimes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ItemsSource should be some kind of sequence (IEnumerable).

Since you are binding DataContext directly, DataContext should be IEnumerable

So instead of single item:

```
DataContext = New Employee()
```

you still have to use collection:

```
Class MainWindow
    Dim appRow As New ObservableCollection(Of Employee)

    Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    appRow.Add(New Employee())
    
    DataContext = appRow
    End Sub
End Class
```

but initialization happens inside Employee class

---

or you can add item to Items colection without binding:

```
Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    MyDataGrid.Items.Add(New Employee())
End Sub
```

changes in xaml:

```
<DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works for now. But is it possible to Bind Datagrid with the Class directly? Maybe ItemsSource="{Binding Employee}"? So I can skip the part too, and gets the same what I initially asked for?

Comment: No, it is not possible. As I said, ItemsSource should be some kind of sequence (IEnumerable). You can use 3 separate ComboBoxes without DataGrid, if you want to work with a single item

Comment: you can add item to Items colection without binding